# Spring @Autowired fields are null. I am using @AutoWired Fields in different class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Here is my code for class where `@Autowired` fields are there:

TestA

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring.xml")
public abstract class TestA extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    @Value("#{environment.username}")
    public String username;

    @Autowired
    @Value("#{environment.password}")
    public String password;

    @Autowired
    @Value("#{environment.passwordtoken}")
    public String passwordToken;
}
```

Here is my another class where I am trying to use the above String variables

```
public class TestData extends TestA {

    ForceApi api;


    public void setApi() {
        // Instantiating api by setting username and pwd
        System.out.println("In getApi");
        ApiConfig ac = new ApiConfig();
        ac.setUsername(username);
        ac.setPassword(passwordToken);             ac.setLoginEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0/");

        api = new ForceApi(ac);
    }

    public void pTestData() {

        setApi();
        // Create test data for play group admin
        String idSoql = "SELECT id FROM PlayGroup__c";

        List<Map> mapResults = api.query(idSoql).getRecords();
    }
}
```

And trying to execute the test using the below class:

```
public class TestB extends TestA{
    @Test(dataProvider="browsers")
    public void test1(){
        TestData td = new TestData();
        td.pTestData();
    }

}
```

Please help me identify where I am doing wrong. I am getting Null Pointer exception in this line:

```
List<Map> mapResults = api.query(idSoql).getRecords();
```

Comment: Only option I can see is that `query()` returns null... ? (if it's correct that this is the line)

Comment: This is not related to @Autowired, seems your query is null... Did you tried to debug ?!

Comment: @Betlista sorry I didn't saw your comment

Comment: Query returned 2 rows:   Id
1 a0J61000001OB61EAG
2 a0J61000001OB66EAG  . The problem I have identified during debug process is userName and passwordToken are Null even though they are set. If I give hard coded username and password it worked totally fine

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above issue myself.

I have used @Service("testdata") in the class where I am using @Autowired fields

```
@Service("testdata")
public class TestData extends TestA {

ForceApi api;


public void setApi() {
    // Instantiating api by setting username and pwd
    System.out.println("In getApi");
    ApiConfig ac = new ApiConfig();
    ac.setUsername(username);
    ac.setPassword(passwordToken);             ac.setLoginEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0/");

    api = new ForceApi(ac);
}

public void pTestData() {

    setApi();
    // Create test data for play group admin
    String idSoql = "SELECT id FROM PlayGroup__c";

    List<Map> mapResults = api.query(idSoql).getRecords();
}
```

}

And in the TestB changed as below

```
public class TestB extends TestA{
@Test(dataProvider="browsers")
public void test1(){
    TestData td = (TestData )applicationContext.getBean("testdata");
    td.pTestData();
}
```

}

and in spring.xml added bean as below

```
<bean id="testdata" class="data.TestData"/>
```

that solved my problem with Null pointer Exception.

Comment: good that you found your solution. But the question is incomplete to arrive at this answer. You have not shared exception stack trace etc etc. Please update the question with necessary details so that if someone faces the same issue they can use this thread for finding answers.